# Code for transfering images from localhost to cpanel web server

Tags: php, android, laravel

I am gettting this error for moving file from my local machine to Cpanel Web Server.The Error is:- failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections

I am Tried this code:-

```
<?php
$flag=0;
$uploads_dir ="http://mysubdomain.in";

 foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
 if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];

    $name = basename($_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key]);
    echo $name;
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/".$name);
   $flag=1;
    }
  else
$flag=0;
  }
if($flag==1)
echo 'uploaded successfully';
else
echo 'Failed to upload';
  ?>
```

Error on this line:-
 move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/".$name);

failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections

Comment: You cannot upload some object via plain http, the protocol does not support this. You would need a sftp server, a ssh server or a webav server for that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `file_put_contents(http url)` you need to use the server path **(e.g. /var/www/html/...).**

You cannot open a file over HTTP and expect it to be written. Instead you need to open it using the local path.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to transfer images from localhost to a cPanel is to use FTP or SFTP using FileZilla or any FTP client.

You can also use the builtin cPanel --> File Manager to upload images.